# how to change screen resolution in rhel/centos 6?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, centos6, rhel6

I have cent os 6 dvd installed on my computer.my monitor resolution is 1920 X 1080.
i cannot increase screen resolution to 1920 X 1080.
system->preference->Display can give maximum resolution as 1280 X 1024.
in centos 6 there is no system-config-display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mother board graphics driver does not support centos6.the better solution is to use another linux varient.If you need centos,you can use centos 6.2.

Please replay the result if you successfully run centos 6.2

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The generic video drivers that ship with CentOS/RHEL don't normally support many resolutions. You'll have to install the drivers for your specific video card.

Comment: is cent os 6.2 support my card?

Comment: How can I possibly answer that? You haven't said what card you have.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you can do Ctrl-Alt-<keypad plus key> or Ctrl-Alt-<keypad minus key> to change the resolution on the fly.  See for instance, https://askubuntu.com/questions/3983/what-does-the-ctrl-alt-shortcut-do

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @8bitjunkie care to give more of a reason? How is it not an answer? I posted specific instructions that have worked for me in the past.